# Can custom alert view in ios5 make my app rejected

Tags: iphone, ios5, uialertview

I have a custom alert view class with layoutsubviews and draw rect method.Is Apple rejecting because of it?

Thanks

Comment: We can't tell you what Apple will and will not allow. Was you app rejected, then Apple will have supplied an reason. If you think Apple might reject your please explain why. As long as you do not use ant private API's or break any rules in the app store guidelines you should be oke.

Comment: the Apple Developer Guideline is your Bible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People add subviews to UIAlertView all the time, usually textFields and activityIndicators. I don't see why custom drawing would be out the question.  Don't incorporate any private methods, Apple review has an automated test that will detect that.

If you get rejected you will get an explicit reason, so you'll know what to fix.

If you're that paranoid, just create a UIView subclass that resembles an AlertView. You'll need some photoshop chops though :-)